# Apache, Redirecting html root to Tomcat(Updated)

Tags: apache-2.4, tomcat

I have just moved my apache2/Tomcat9 server from windows to ubuntu.
ProxyPass and ProxyPassReverse are working fine. Known tomcat webapp urls are all passing through.

However, when I just enter the www.myservername.com it goes to the default var/www directory.

I tried redirecting using `000-default.conf`. The following works for `http://www.myservername.com` but does not work for `https://www.myservername.com`

ServerName www.myservername.com

```
ServerName www.myservername.com
<VirtualHost *:*>

    ServerName www.myservername.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    Redirect permanent / https://www.myservername.com/ddd-college-website/entry
</VirtualHost>
```

So, in short, typing `https://www.myservername.com/` into the browser, should take users to `https://www.myservername.com/ddd-college-website/entry`. But it's not happening

Any advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

For ServerName set just the Servername, not the portnumber.
And for the Redirect it is `Redirect permanent / https://whatever/`

Comment: actually, the problem was only with https....not surprising since port is set to 80.....my mistake